# For-each Loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I have a sample code which creates an "array" of size 10 and tries to initialize it with reverse values in a For loop e.g:(9,8,7,6,5...0):

```
int[] array = new int[10];
        for (int i = array.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
            System.out.println("Present value of i=" + i
                    + " Present value of j=" + j);
            array[j] = i;
            System.out.println("Array:" + j + "=" + i);
        }
        for (int k : array) {
            System.out.println(array[k]);
        }
```

So far so good. This is the output from console which is perfect:

```
Present value of i=9 Present value of j=0
Array:0=9
Present value of i=8 Present value of j=1
Array:1=8
Present value of i=7 Present value of j=2
Array:2=7
Present value of i=6 Present value of j=3
Array:3=6
Present value of i=5 Present value of j=4
Array:4=5
Present value of i=4 Present value of j=5
Array:5=4
Present value of i=3 Present value of j=6
Array:6=3
Present value of i=2 Present value of j=7
Array:7=2
Present value of i=1 Present value of j=8
Array:8=1
Present value of i=0 Present value of j=9
Array:9=0
```

**The issue is with For-each loop in the end which is just printing the values in array:**

```
for (int k : array) {
            System.out.println(array[k]);
        }
```

The values printed array are 0,1,2...9 where it should be 9,8,7...0

When I use the regular For loop to print the array, it works normally. Am I missing some funny business here?

Comment: What does `for (int k : array)` mean? What does `array[k]` mean?

Comment: What values are _in_ your array?

Comment: Throwing this out there; **Java != Javascript**. The way you're doing things is how javascript works; an advanced `for...in` loop iterates keys of an object.

Java's for-each loop only works with *values*; it has no concept of keys.

Comment: Just a rule of thumb; standard `for` loops are pretty standard across languages. For-each loops, however, are pretty different across the board. Never assume a foreach loop works the same, or even exists, in another language! :)

Comment: @Makoto print out is already given in the question :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Values are assigned to array in the first For loop itself

Comment: I now realize that in my haste, the output wouldn't change from what you're printing, since what you're printing and what you're adding to the array are 1:1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, since `(int k : array)` causes `k` to go through the *values* in the array, not the indexes, what you've done is equivalent to

```
System.out.println(array[array[0]]);
System.out.println(array[array[1]]);
System.out.println(array[array[2]]);
System.out.println(array[array[3]]);
...
System.out.println(array[array[9]]);
```

which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 11):

You are already getting the values out of the `array` with your foreach loop, which you are using as an index again into the array, yielding the values in order again.

Just print `k`.  Change

```
for (int k : array) {
    System.out.println(array[k]);
}
```

to

```
for (int k : array) {
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

End of the output:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: For anyone confused; `for(var key in array){var val = array[key]}` is how you can iterate keys in Javascript. Java's foreach loops work with values directly. I think this is the source of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This for loop, for (int k : array) is basically gives you the array value in detail this for loop is like -

int k = array[0] = 9
int k = array[1] = 8 .....

and again you are trying to print array[9] , array[8] which gives you result like 0,1,2...
replace 
for( `int` k : array){
    `System`.`out`.`println`(array[k]);
}

with
for(`int` k : array){
    `System`.`out`.`println`(k);
}